# О значении слова "дефолт" и выражения Дефолт-сити

Tags: этимология, лексика

В словаре указано следующее:

**ДЕФОЛТ** [англ. default — невыполнение обязательств] **Экон**. 1. **Неисполнение договора**; невыполнение обязательства, неуплата долга. // Финансовая несостоятельность. 2. **Отказ** (банка, правительства) выплатить по каким-л. причинам свои внешние или внутренние долги или проценты по ним.

Но дефолт — это еще **default option**, то есть **опция по умолчанию**, вариант по умолчанию.

**Например, Москву называют Дефолт-сити.** Если не знать этого значения (по умолчанию), то что можно подумать?

И вопрос из области этимологии: **Что общего между двумя этими значениями?**

Comment: 1) Вопрос в том, почему экономический термин обозначен в словаре, а компьютерный термин нет. Я думаю, что он уже давно присутствует в специальной литературе, но не все пользователи языка с ним знакомы.  Поэтому в словарь Кузнецова (обновленный в 2014 году) не мешало бы его внести.  Конечно Москву называют Дефолт-сити  при соответствующем контексте, например: Поздравляю всех жителей Дефолт-сити с наступающим Днем города. (Сложно сказать, какие эмоции при этом выражаются, раздражение, насмешка или еще что.

Comment: 2) Дефолт - это уже наше слово, хотя и заимствованное, поэтому меня интересует русская (не английская) этимология, а с этим я никак пока не разберусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этимология слова имеет латинские корни "de-" + "fallere", что может означает примерно "без мошенничества" или "отказ от обязательств".  То есть сторона потерпевшая дефолт честно объявляла об этом, не пытаясь обманывать другие заинтересованные стороны.

В склонном к многозначности современном английском языке это слово имеет несколько различных значений, которые сходны в своей семантике образования. В частности, значение из сферы программного обеспечения ("по умолчанию") буквально могло бы означать примерно следующее: "при отказе от выполнения каких-то либо действий". В русском языке это слово получило наиболее близкий перевод к своему буквальному значению: "без других действий" = "по умолчанию".

**Дополнение** (в ответ на вопросы и комментарии Sharon).

История появления этого слова в русском языке мне представляется совершенно прозрачной — это типичное заимствование, когда носители языка переносят слово из другого языка в подходящем (или привычном) по их мнению контексте. Поэтому, чтобы понять появление омонимичных значений этого слова, нужно обратиться к языку, из которого оно было заимствовано.

В латинском это слово буквально означало что-то вроде "отказ от обязательств". Впервые появившись в английском (в начале XIII в.), оно приобрело значение "преступление, грех", но уже к концу XIII в. значение изменилось до "неудача, бездействие". Можно предположить*, что первое из этих значений к середине XIX в. (1858 г.) привело к появлению юридического термина, а второе — в середине XX в. (1966 г.) — компьютерного.

*Это моё предположение. Но даты и факты я взял из английских этимологических словарей (воспользовавшись компьютерным переводом).

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ.  Только вот я никак не разберусь до конца в этих двух "дефолтах". Понятно, что присутствует отказ от платежей или от выполнения действий. А дальше? Слово fault  (англ.) - ошибка, дефект, вина, проступок, а default - это уже неисполнение. А  какой исходный глагол  (в англ. и латинском вариантах)? Тоже не могу понять..

Comment: @Sharon Я дополнил свой ответ. Нужно понимать, что в английском слова fault и default, хотя имеют общие этимологические корни, но не более того. Слово default этимологически не является производным английского слова fault, оно было заимствовано из старофранцузского цельным словом.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за интересный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Что общего между двумя этими значениями? С точки зрения русского языка общее то, что оба значения пришли из английского языка, где словo default тоже имеет два различных значения (более глубокий анализ будет касаться происхождения этих значений в английском).

Заметим, что default city в английском тоже можно понимать двояко (как город, выбираемый по умолчанию, и как город-банкрот или город банкротов), и только контекст вносит ясность.

> How To Set A **Default City** For Weather

Это о том, погоду в каком городе будет показывать ваш смартфон по умолчанию (если город не указан).

> Welcome to **Default City**...1 million people default on their student debt... (https://bonefidewealth.com/blog/welcome-to-default-city/)

Здесь речь идет о городе банкротов.

> What should we do if more and more cities go “bankrupt”? Once occur, such as Wuhan **default City**, there will be two situations: one is the emergence of a large number of bad debts of banks. (https://sixidiots.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/will-wuhan-go-bankrupt-due-to-the-government-debt-crisis/)

А здесь — о городах-банкротах.

Так что я бы поостерегся называть Москву *дефолт-сити* без соответствующего контекста, тем более что такое значение дефолта, как "выбираемое по умолчанию", еще не закреплено в общих словарях.

Нужно подчеркнуть, что слова default city в отрыве от контекста ставят носителей английского в тупик (это относится и к упомянутому варианту с поздравлением жителей default city — факт поздравления не вносит никакой ясности). Чтобы англичанину или американцу стало ясно, о чем речь, нужно указать, из какой области этот default option (чаще всего это default city for weather или default city for location). Таким образом *дефолт-сити* как особое понятие — чисто российское изобретение.